# json-server 0.8.12 and Express 4.x Routing

Tags: node.js, express, json-server

I have an existing node-express project running on express using express server and have middlewares and routing on express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('/path/to/express_conf_file')(app);
app.listen(config.port);
```

I want to use json-server for easy mocking and I've followed [this](http://nmotw.in/json-server/). My current code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('json-server'); 
var middlewares = express(); 
var server = app.create(); // Returns an Express server 
**var router = server.router('db.json');** // Returns an Express router
server.use(middlewares); 
server.use(router); 
require('./config/express')(middlewares, config); 
server.listen(4000);
```

server.route('db.json') seems to be deprecated in Express 4.x. What needs to be done to use 'db.json' with express 4.x?

I am invoking my application and json-server using `concurrenrly` using `npm start` and in package.json I've defined:

```
"js-server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 4000",
"start": "concurrently \"gulp command\" \"npm run js-server\""
```

Can somebody please advice as what should be the correct way of using json-server with Express 4.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/253). json-server can be mounted at a certain path within express server. No need to start the json-server separately now. Only `gulp command` can be used to launch express server.

The json server can be hosted separately also and can be accessed through the specified port from different appilication(s).